# Is it possible to re-import .kix files as Google Docs files?

Tags: import, google-api, upload, google-drive-api

Google Docs are stored in a format called .kix. You can get the .kix of a document by appending export?format=kix to a Google Docs file. Is it possible using the APIs to re-import this file as a Google Doc rather than a plaintext file? I don't see it as an option in the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_)

> When creating a file in Google Drive, you can convert **some** types file into a Google Docs, Sheets or Slides document by specifying the mimeType property of the file. The following sample shows how to upload a CSV file as a spreadsheet:

The supported conversions are available dynamically in the [About resource's](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) importFormats array and include:

> Microsoft Word, OpenDocument Text, HTML, RTF, plain text ->    Google Docs
>
> Microsoft Excel, OpenDocument Spreadsheet, CSV, TSV, plain text    -> Google Sheets
>
> Microsoft Powerpoint, OpenDocument Presentation    -> Google Slides
>
> JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, PDF ->    Google Docs (embeds the image in a Doc)
>
> plain text (special MIME type), JSON ->    Google Apps Script

This is the full import list i found on my own account from the about resource

```
,
 "importFormats": {
  "text/tab-separated-values": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "image/jpeg": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "image/bmp": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "image/gif": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "image/pjpeg": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.script+text/plain": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.script"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-excel": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "text/rtf": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "text/plain": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "image/png": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/msword": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/pdf": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/json": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.script"
  ],
  "application/x-msmetafile": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "image/x-bmp": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/rtf": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "image/x-png": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "text/html": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.script"
  ],
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "text/csv": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
  ],
  "image/jpg": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ],
  "text/richtext": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
  ]
 },
 "exportFormats": {
  "application/vnd.google-apps.document": [
   "application/rtf",
   "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
   "text/html",
   "application/pdf",
   "application/epub+zip",
   "application/zip",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
   "text/plain"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet": [
   "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
   "text/tab-separated-values",
   "application/pdf",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
   "text/csv",
   "application/zip",
   "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.jam": [
   "application/pdf"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.script": [
   "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": [
   "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
   "application/pdf",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
   "text/plain"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.form": [
   "application/zip"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing": [
   "image/svg+xml",
   "image/png",
   "application/pdf",
   "image/jpeg"
  ],
  "application/vnd.google-apps.site": [
   "text/plain"
  ]
```

kix  is not a supported mimeType nor is it possible for you to add your own import type definition in the about resource.